# Merge in R large number of data tables with different row count vertically with additional column for each original list in the merged list

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I've OHLC+Volume data for AAPL, GOOG, TXN etc (all the constituents of S&P 500) in individual data tables loaded in R environment. All the data tables has 7 columns, but not all has equal number of rows.

I need to merge **all** the tables, one top of another. To distinguish between various companies in the merged table, need a additional column which will have the name of the original tables for all the rows taken from the original table. No list of tables to be merged exists. Need to merge all existing tables in the R workspace. Apologies for  being unclear.

Also the performance might be an issues; it could easily cross to more that 3 mn rows with 8 rows. Tried with plyr and reshape, but of no avail.

As an example:

```
Table1: named AAPL

   col1 col2
1. 2    4
2. 3    11 

Table2: named GOOG

   col1 col2
1. 10    12
2. 14    19
3. 11    15 


Merged Table: named OUTPUT

   col1 col2  col3
1. 2    4     AAPL
2. 3    11    AAPL
3. 10   12    GOOG
4. 14   19    GOOG
5. 11   15    GOOG
```

Sample of the actual data:

```
 > str(ASTRAZEN)
'data.frame':   3440 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ DATE  : int  20130628 20130628 20130628 20130628 20130628 20130628 20130628 20130628 20130628 20130628 ...
 $ TIME  : int  916 917 918 919 920 921 922 923 924 925 ...
 $ CLOSE : num  660 658 654 657 654 ...
 $ HIGH  : num  660 660 655 657 656 ...
 $ LOW   : num  653 654 654 652 652 ...
 $ OPEN  : num  654 660 655 654 655 ...
 $ VOLUME: int  522 265 320 498 417 138 135 975 132 126 ...`

> head(ASTRAZEN)
      DATE TIME  CLOSE   HIGH    LOW   OPEN VOLUME
1 20130628  916 659.95 659.95 652.55 654.00    522
2 20130628  917 658.00 659.95 654.20 659.95    265
3 20130628  918 654.00 655.00 654.00 655.00    320
4 20130628  919 656.65 656.65 652.50 654.00    498
5 20130628  920 653.65 655.85 651.95 655.00    417
6 20130628  921 654.00 654.50 654.00 654.50    138
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not very clear how you're going to have a list of names in OP, but assuming it's literally a list of names, you can do this:

```
library(data.table)
aapl = data.table(col1 = c(2:3), col2 = c(4,11))
goog = data.table(col1 = c(10:12), col2 = c(1:3))

sp = list('aapl', 'goog')
rbindlist(lapply(sp, function(name) get(name)[, col3 := name]))
#   col1 col2 col3
#1:    2    4 aapl
#2:    3   11 aapl
#3:   10    1 goog
#4:   11    2 goog
#5:   12    3 goog
```

---

**edit**

If you'd like to list all of the `data.frame` objects in your environment, and then do the above, you can do:

```
all.objects = sapply(ls(), function(x) class(get(x)))
sp = names(all.objects[all.objects == 'data.frame'])
rbindlist(lapply(sp, function(name) data.table(get(name))[, col3 := name]))
```

Comment: This is almost working, only need to generate the variable 'sp' out of all the existing data tables in the workspace.

Comment: @fragrant try this: `sp <- tables(silent=TRUE)$NAME`

Comment: @GSee the command gives me empty variable of characteristic "<unknown>[0]"

Comment: @fragrant make sure you have data.tables in your environment; try `test = data.table(a = 2); tables(silent=T)$NAME`

Comment: it seems the data is stored as list, not as tables

`> typeof('ABB')
[1] "character"
> typeof(ABB)
[1] "list"`

tried to make one into table
`> as.table(ABB)
Error in as.table.default(ABB) : cannot coerce into a table`

Comment: table and data.table are very different objects, and you'd be looking for either `data.table(` or `as.data.table(`, but it's not clear to me now what your data is any more - maybe edit OP and add `dput` of head of your data, or an example of how to construct your data